# My MainMenu.xib refuses to go into the bundle and my app crashes with: "Unable to load nib file: MainMenu, exiting"

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xib, nib

When I run my application in Debug mode from Xcode it works, but when I run it in Release mode it crashes after outputting this:

```
Unable to load nib file: MainMenu, exiting
```

Indeed, MainMenu.xib is not present in either bundle (Debug nor Release) and if I look at the configuration it looks like it's missing:

[image]

It's been like that since I created the app from a fresh template but I didn't think much of it because in Debug it was working. I tried removing it and adding it again and it's still shown red, as missing.

In Deployment Info it says MainMenu although in the list it says MainMenu.xib. When I select MainMenu.xib it shows MainMenu:

[image]

Running by double clicking on the .app files has the same result as running it from Xcode.

What's wrong here? how do I fix it?

The environment is Xcode 6.2, a Cocoa application with Swift (OSX) and I'm running this in Yosemite (some other devs are running Mavericks).

Comment: The settings you've shown look normal (including the red `MainMenu.xib`). Check under `Targets > Info > Custom OS X Application Target Properties` : The string value of `Main nib file base name`  should be `MainMenu` (you can check this value in `Info.plist` as well). You should actually check the compiled .app for `MainMenu.nib` and ***not*** `MainMenu.xib`, since normally the `.xib` gets flattened and translated into a `.nib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record:

```
Unable to load nib file: MainMenu, exiting
```

was a real error but all the other symptoms that I saw were not relevant as @I'L'l commented in the question.

I am not sure what the actual problem was because the problem went away on its own after cleaning the project and rebuilding. I suspect a script that I had to generate DMGs might have been causing some issues. Also, I was expecting the .app that Xcode generated to work on other machines and that's not realistic. You need to properly re-archive the app for that to happen:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html